# DisplayPort without AUX channel

Tags: displayport

Reading the VESA 1.2 spec it seems that the AUX channel may not be essential to the correct functioning of the video channel, i.e. if we already know the EDID data and don't need to do any calibration, i.e. in an embedded device. So, is it feasible to use the DisplayPort without using the AUX channel at all?

Comment: Define feasible.  With most controllers it is possible to get it working depending on what controller, what panel and what OS you are using.

Comment: What conditions could make it feasible regarding the agents you mention? I mean, what should a controller or panel offer to be viable to get rid of the AUX channel? In our case, we are using an LVDS panel, a DP to LVDS bridget(PTN3460) and Linux. I've been looking closely to the spec and it seems to me that not using the AUX channel means not being able to change or read the DPCD registers, which i.e forbids setting the power mode (see the SET_POWER dpcd); it seems to me that this is a great drawback. How it is done in the scenarios you mention?